# What is the Pythonic way of reordering a list consisting of dicts?

Tags: sorting, python, lambda

I have the the following list:

```
list = [{'nr' : 2, 'name': 'streamname'}, {'nr' : 3,'name': 'streamname'}, {'nr' : 1, 'name': 'streamname'}]
```

So how would I reorder it to become like this in an efficient way in python?

```
list = [{'nr' : 1, 'name': 'streamname'}, {'nr' : 2,'name': 'streamname'}, {'nr' : 3, 'name': 'streamname'}]
```

I came up with using sort and creating a lambda function to sort it. Is this a good way? And is it efficient?

```
list.sort(cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x['nr'], y['nr']))
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, using `cmp=` is not efficient. Use `key=` instead. Like so:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda x: x['nr'])
```

The reason is simple: `cmp` compares two objects. If your list is long, there are many combinations of two objects you can have to compare, so a list that is twice as long takes much more than twice as long to sort.

But with `key` this is not the case and sorting long lists are hence *much* faster.

But the main reason to use `key` instead of `cmp` is that it's much easier to use.

Also, `sorted`() has a benefit over `.sort()`, it can take any iterable, while `.sort()` inly works on lists.

Comment: Yea was looking into it, but it didn't work when I used key=x['nr'] little stupid that I didn't make an lambda function for that also.. Works great! Guess I can accept your answer soon, but will keep it open for some hours.

Comment: You could also use `itemgetter` from the `operator` module instead of having to write your own lambda function and it would be faster also.

Comment: I don't get it. Basic operation of _every_ sort algorithm is comparison of two elements. I don't see how using `key` instead of `cmp` makes difference. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Piotr - each `cmp` operation needs two variables to be compared - with `key` you define these variables, the rest is simple comparison... Imagine you could use `cmp` if there was something else than a simple < = > comparison to be done (a special function or other criteria)

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogast: The point is that the cmp method needs to be called once for each comparison, but the key method just once for each value. It's the call that is expensive, not the comparison.

Comment: @milkypostman: I just tried it with 5 million items on Python 2.6.5. The lambda too 14.5 seconds, the itemgetter 16.2. So it's in fact around 10% slower. ;) (I don't know why. they *should* be equivalent, as they do the same thing. But there you go.)

Comment: Another possibly important difference to keep in mind between the list `sort` method and the generic `sorted` function is that the former sorts the list in in-place but doesn't return anything, while the latter leaves the original alone and returns a new one.

Comment: @Lennart That would mean that sorting alghorithm would have to first read each key and *tight it* with the object it comes from so that it could use keys' values without ever calling `key` function again. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('nr'))
```